# Помогите найти ошибку в коде(Игра "Жизнь")

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, c++11

Помогите найти ошибку.
Писал клеточный автомат "Жизнь"(описание можно посмотреть на википедии, либо в комментариях к коду ниже).
Когда все вроде бы сделал, обнаружил, что алгоритм на самом деле работает не правильно.
Например, это видно, когда на вход идет такой файл("1.txt"):

```
10 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

По логике игры, "квадратик" имеет стабильное положение и не должен меняться, "полоска" должна "вращаться", а фигура снизу представлять из себя глайдер. Но этого не происходит.
Сначала я думал, ошибка в том, что я не перегрузил оператор присваивания, а стандартный присваивал не значения двумерного массива, а указатель на него (таким образом, оба объекта ссылались на один и тот же массив, и выходила билиберда). Но после того как я оператор присваивания таки перегрузил, поведение программы не изменилось.

```
        /** \file
  * \brief Клеточный автомат "Жизнь"
  *
  * Программа реализует клеточный автомат "Жизнь"("Life").
  * Дано поле, в котормо каждая клетка может быть либо "живой", либо "мертвой".
  * Пользователь задает начальные условия - первое поколение. Программа генерирует новое поколения (состояние поля) по таким правилам:
  * Если клетка имеет более 3 или менее 2 соседей, она становится/остается мертвой.
  * Если клетка имеет строго 3 соседя, она становится/остается живой.
  * Новые поколения генерируется до тех пор, пока все клетки клетки не умрут либо не образуют стабильное состояние (перестанут меняться).
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <windows.h>

//#include <chrono>
//#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Fields {
    /* Класс описывает состояние поля ("Поколения жизни"). */
    private:
        int n; // количество рядков поля
        int m; // количество столбцов поля
        bool **array; //игровое поле. Если клетка поля true - она жива, если false - мертва.
    public:
        Fields(int a, int b);
        Fields(const Fields& );
        Fields(ifstream &);
        Fields& operator= (const Fields&);
        void print();
        void run( const Fields last);
};

int countOfChanges = 1; //счетчик изменений состояния игрового поля .

int main(){
    int countLife = 0; //счетчик состояний игрового поля("Поколений жизни")
    int n, m; //длинна и ширина поля
    cout << "Hello. This is game of life. " << endl
         << "1. Create the random generated field" << endl
         << "2. Create the field with file" << endl;
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    Fields current(0, 0); // текущее поколение


    switch(choice){
        case 1:{
            cout << "Enter the number of rows and columns of field" << endl;
            cout << setw(9) << "Rows: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << setw(9) << "Columns: ";
            cin >> m;
            Fields randomField = Fields(n, m);
            current = randomField;
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            ifstream fin("1.txt");
            Fields fileField = Fields(fin);
            current = fileField;
            break;
        }
    }

    Fields next(current); // следующее поколение

    cout << "Field: "<< endl;
    current.print();

    while (countOfChanges != 0){
        //system("cls");
        cout << ++countLife << "st generation: " << endl;
        countOfChanges = 0;
        next.run(current);
        current = next;
        current.print();
        Sleep(1000);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    //system("cls");

    cout << endl << "This system has been alive for " << countLife - 1 << " steps." << endl;

    return 0;
}

void Fields:: run( const Fields last ){

    /* Метод реализует логику игры. Проходит по всем клеткам поля last,
       считает количество соседей у каждой клетки и устанавливает новое состояние аналогичной клетки своего поля.
       Если изменения происходят, счетчик изменений увеличивается.
    */
    int neighbors = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            /* Вот здесь при некоторых [i][j] без всякой видимой причины 
            почему-то меняются array[i][j] и last.array[i][j], хотя это ни в коем случаи происходить не должно. */
            neighbors = 0; //количество живых клеток-соседей

            if ( j - 1 > 0 ){   //тут и далее: проверка, не выходит ли "сосед" за пределы массива, чтобы можно было к нему обратиться
                if(last.array[i][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n && j - 1 > 0) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j] ){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n && j + 1 < m) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( j + 1  <  m) {
                if(last.array[i][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i - 1 > 0 && j + 1 < m ){
                if(last.array[i-1][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i - 1 > 0 ){
                if(last.array[i-1][j]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if (  i -1 > 0 && j - 1 > 0){
                if(last.array[i-1][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }


            if (neighbors == 3 && last.array[i][j] == false){
                //если соседей строго 3, мертвая клетка оживает
                array[i][j] = true;
                ::countOfChanges++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (neighbors == 3 && last.array[i][j] == true){
                continue;
            }
            else if ( (neighbors <= 2 || neighbors > 3 ) && last.array[i][j] == true) {
                //если соседей меньше или равно 2 или больше 3, живая клетка умирает
                array[i][j] = false;
                ::countOfChanges++;
                continue;
            }
            else if ( (neighbors <=2 || neighbors > 3) && last.array[i][j] ==false ){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

Fields:: Fields(int a, int b): n(a), m(b){

    array = new bool* [n];                         // объявление динамического двумерного массива
    for(int count = 0; count < n; count ++){        //
        array[count] = new bool [m];                //
    }                                               //

    mt19937 gen(time(0));                           // генератор псевдо-случайных чисел из с++11
    uniform_int_distribution <> dist(0, 1);         // распределение рандомайзера - целые числа 0 и 1
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            array[i][j] = dist(gen);                // рандомное заполнение двумерного массива 0 и 1
        }
    }
}

Fields:: Fields(const Fields& last){
    /* Конструктор копирования */

    n = last.n;
    m = last.m;

    array = new bool* [n];                         // объявление динамического двумерного массива
    for(int count = 0; count < n; count ++){        //
        array[count] = new bool [m];                //
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            array[i][j] = last.array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Fields:: Fields(ifstream & fin){
    /* Создание поля с файла*/
    fin >> n;
    fin >> m;

    array = new bool * [n];                         // объявление динамического двумерного массива
    for(int count = 0; count < n; count ++){        //
        array[count] = new bool [m];                //
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            fin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Fields& Fields:: operator = (const Fields &right){
    n = right.n;
    m = right.m;


    delete []array;

    array = new bool * [n];                         // объявление динамического двумерного массива
    for(int count = 0; count < n; count ++){        //
        array[count] = new bool [m];                //
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            array[i][j] = right.array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

void Fields:: print(){

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if(array[i][j]){
                cout << "*";
            }
            else{
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

**UPD:** Ошибка в методе run. Комментаторы указали, что ошибка в том, что матрица переписывается "по живому", но это однозначно не так. Алгоритм сверяется с прошлым значением и записывает в текущую. 
Но, есть один нюанс, который я ничем не могу объяснить и, соответственно, пофиксить:
В методе run в цикле в определенный момент (например когда i = 1, j =0 при тех начальных данных, что я указал), и array[i][j], и, что самое главное, last.array[i][j] изменяют свое значение без какой-либо видимой причины (они вообще не попадают в тот блок который меняет значение). При чем last.array[i][j] вообще как константа передается, и по логике вещей, меняться никак не может. В остальных случаях, когда программа заходит в тот блок, где значение меняются - все работает корректно.

Вот сам код метода с указанием момента, где это происходит:

```
void Fields:: run( const Fields last ){

    /* Метод реализует логику игры. Проходит по всем клеткам поля last,
       считает количество соседей у каждой клетки и устанавливает новое состояние аналогичной клетки своего поля.
       Если изменения происходят, счетчик изменений увеличивается.
    */
    int neighbors = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            /* Вот здесь при некоторых [i][j] без всякой видимой причины 
            почему-то меняются array[i][j] и last.array[i][j], хотя это ни в коем случаи происходить не должно. */
            neighbors = 0; //количество живых клеток-соседей

            if ( j - 1 > 0 ){   //тут и далее: проверка, не выходит ли "сосед" за пределы массива, чтобы можно было к нему обратиться
                if(last.array[i][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n && j - 1 > 0) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j] ){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i + 1 < n && j + 1 < m) {
                if(last.array[i+1][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( j + 1  <  m) {
                if(last.array[i][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i - 1 > 0 && j + 1 < m ){
                if(last.array[i-1][j+1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if ( i - 1 > 0 ){
                if(last.array[i-1][j]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
            if (  i -1 > 0 && j - 1 > 0){
                if(last.array[i-1][j-1]){
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }


            if (neighbors == 3 && last.array[i][j] == false){
                //если соседей строго 3, мертвая клетка оживает
                array[i][j] = true;
                ::countOfChanges++;
                continue;
            }
            else if (neighbors == 3 && last.array[i][j] == true){
                continue;
            }
            else if ( (neighbors <= 2 || neighbors > 3 ) && last.array[i][j] == true) {
                //если соседей меньше или равно 2 или больше 3, живая клетка умирает
                array[i][j] = false;
                ::countOfChanges++;
                continue;
            }
            else if ( (neighbors <=2 || neighbors > 3) && last.array[i][j] ==false ){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2:**
Нашел ошибку. Код вида

```
> for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
>         for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){} }
```

В любом месте программы при некоторых [i][j] самовольно меняет array[i][j] и last.array[i][j]
При тех входных данных это происходит в точках [1][0] [1][7] [2][0] [2][7]
Что это за черная магия?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и обширный. Отладчиком найдите функцию, которая работает не так - и уже по ней спрашивайте.

Comment: в `if (neighbors == 3 && last.array[i][j] == false){` вы делаете `array[i][j] = true;` тут кажется должна быть `last.array[i][j] = true;` так как проверяете один массив, оживляете в другом

Answer (score 3):

У Вас один массив. Вы в него пишите новое состояние клеток и поэтому эти изменения сразу влияют на другие клетки.

Можете "завести" еще один массив. В новый массив копируем старый и уже новый массив используем для определения кол-ва живых клеток, а новое состояние клеток пишем в старый массив. Таким образом изменения состояния клеток будут учтены только на следующем шаге "жизни".

Comment: Взгляните еще, вы не правы. У меня два массива в двух разных объектах, и читаю я из "предыдущего", а пишу в "текущий".

Ошибку я нашел и добавил ее описание в вопросе, но не могу разобраться как это вообще может быть. Будьте добры, прочтите и взгляните еще раз.